# SSRS does not recognize custom DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I'm developing SSRS reports via VS2010 on my local machine.
I need to reference from a certain report to a DLL I wrote, The DLL was built at .net framwork 3.5 and I've placed the dll in the following libraries:
1.C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies.
2.C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
both on my local machine and the server where SSRS is located.
I've also added rssrvpolicy.config file as following:

```
<CodeGroup
           class="UnionCodeGroup"
           version="1"
           PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
           Name="Test"
           Description="">
         <IMembershipCondition
               class="UrlMembershipCondition"
               version="1"
               Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\Test.dll"
                   />
```

Done all that' I've referenced the DLL through the report properties but yet recieved the following error message while previewing the report:
"An error occured during local report processing, The definition of the report X is invalid.
Error while loading code module "Test ...' Could not load file or assembly 'Test ...' or one of its dependenies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Any ideas?

Comment: For report previewing in VS try adding the assembly to Windows\assembly as well. Not sure about the issue if it's not working server side - is it working through the Report Manager website?

Answer (score 5):

OK found the problem!

Apperntly installing VS2010 on win7 64 bit create two Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 folders, one in Program Files where I've located my DLL and one in Program Files (x86) where I should have located it.
Once the DLL was put in the correct folder the report recognized it.

Thanks for your reply